# Excel 2010 - Copy and Paste numbers with operators without creating a formula

Tags: excel

I'm trying to copy some address book information from one Excel 2010 spreadsheet to another. I have a lot of phone numbers in the source file that are in the format "+X XXX XXX XXXX" or similar. Both of the spreadsheets are set to treat *all* numbers in *every* cell as text.

After searching online I figured out how to copy and paste *one* phone number to a cell on the other spreadsheet without turning both source and destination cells into formulas. It requires that I overwrite the destination cell completely with the contents of the (single) source cell. I have absolutely no clue how to then paste a *second* phone number into the same cell without Excel deciding that the (second) source cell and the destination cell are both formulas. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please explain. Why should this become a formula? Why isn't this a simple copy/past?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: @Tim Soholt I've tried to enter in excel the format you mention in your question and it was not possible. Please provide the exact format, how it looks in the formula bar and in the cell, both in the source file and the pasted file.

Comment: @User15: Original: +44 (0) 20 7602 0706
I hit copy, then click in another cell, and _sometimes_ (not always; I haven't figured out why), the cell becomes a formula cell. Trying to repeat it in a controlled environment, I've only been able to get it to turn the formula to, for example: =AD1492. When I hit Ctrl+V, it becomes =AD1492+44 (0) 20 7602 0706, which is both how it displays in the cell and on the formula bar. I've had stranger formulae show up in both the source and destination cells in the past.

Comment: Clarification: The _source_ cell became a formula cell when testing.